# Serial port DataReceived event does not firing

Tags: c#

I want to read the weight from a weighing scale into my Dot Net Framework programme. The weighing scale is connected to my PC. I need to fetch data from this scale. I am using serial port communication.

My issue is that the DataReceived Event is not firing. Why this event is not firing? Is the problem with my code or a port configuration problem?

```
 private SerialPort _serialPort;
_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
_serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
_serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 9; 
_serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);   
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPortOnDataReceived);
_serialPort.Open();
private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)    
        BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     
    else
    {            
        int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
        if (nbrDataRead == 0)
            return;
        string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        txt_Netwt.Text = str.ToString();
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider posting an actual [mcve].

Comment: Does the communication protocol of the hardware require you to send some kind of trigger to start sending out measurements?

Comment: You have a lot of problems there and this code cannot be run. You're creating a new instance of the SerialPort after you have tried to set property value of a non-existing instance. You should get a `NullReferenceException` right away (unless you have rewritten the original code in a really bad way here instead of copying it) -- Remove that `InvokeRequired` / `BeginInvoke()` (non-working) stuff, you just need `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txt_Netwt.Text = str.ToString()));`

Comment: Well, `str` is already a string, so `... => txt_Netwt.Text = str`.